# How to build a job only if the one before it fails in a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins. I have spent the last few weeks creating jobs to execute chains of shell commands, but now when I tried to find out how to chain jobs together, I have failed to find the answer I was looking for.

I have a CreateStack job, and if it fails somehow, I'd like to run DeleteStack to remove the stuff that CreateStack left behind while failing. If CreateStack does not fail, build the rest of the jobs.

Something like this:

```
b = build(job: "CreateStack", propagate: false, parameters: [string(name: 'TASVersion', value: "$TASVersion"), string(name: 'CloudID', value: "$CloudID"), string(name: 'StackName', value: "$StackName"), booleanParam(name: 'Swap partition required', value: true)]).result

if(b == 'FAILURE') {
    echo "CreateStack has failed. Running DeleteStack."
    build(job: "DeleteStack", parameters: [string(name: 'CloudID', value: "$CloudID"), string(name: 'StackName', value: "$StackName")]
}
else {
    build job: 'TAS Deploy', parameters: [string(name: 'FT_NODE_IP', value: "$FT-NodeIP"), string(name: 'TASVersion', value: "RawTASVersion")]
}
```

Could somebody help me out with this, please?
Also, can I use variables in a pipeline script like this? I set the project to be parameterized and added the necessary choice parameters, e.g.: $StackName

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in a scripted pipeline:

```
node {
    try {
        stage('CreateStack') {
            build(job: 'CreateStack', parameters: [<parameters>])
        }
        stage('OtherJobs') {
            #build the rest of the jobs
        }
    } catch (error) {
        build(job: 'DeleteStack', parameters: [<parameters>])
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        throw error
    } finally {
        build(job: 'LastJob', parameters: [<parameters>])
    }
}
```

Please note, that the `catch` block is executed if any job fails. There you have to implent a little additional logic.